# Forward a WebHook to another URL

Tags: webhooks

First to say, that I don't know to write code in php, maybe that was my solution, so i need your help please :-)

I have a URL like this "https://example1.com/something" and a 3rd party app, is sending a webhook to this URL.

I need to automatic forwarding the webhook arrived, to another URL like: "https://example2.com/somethingelse"

The reason I'm looking something like this, is because the 3rd party app, does not accept my final URL   .

Is this possible and how can do it?

Kind regards

Eddie

Answer (score 1):

After some research, even i don't know php, i found the solution, by searching the web.
Here is the solution I found, so it will be available for anyone who needs it in the future. Μaybe there is a better approach, but this works!
(I didn't understand why sending the $webhookin directly didn't work and i had to decode and encode it again)

```
$webhookin = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$data = json_decode($webhookin);

$webhookout = json_encode($data);
$webhookout = json_encode($webhookout);

$url = 'https://example2.com/somethingelse';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $webhookout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

kind regards

Eddie

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.reliablewebhook.com/

1. Replace the "https://example1.com/something" url in your 3rd party app with the one that ReliableWebhook will generate in the left column (Webhook URLs).
2. Then add your "https://example2.com/somethingelse" url in the left column (Destination URLs)

As a result, you should have a simple bridge and as a bonus you will be able to track all requests

Comment: thank you for your time to answer. This is a very nice solution, but doesn't cover me. As i wrote,, the reason is that the 3rd party app asks for a specific url/domain

Answer (score 0):

Try https://webhookdump.link

The service also provides the CLI tools to forward the HTTP request to the target URL in real-time.